Get screenshot without too many margin Forge Viewer
For the past few days, I'm struggling to take an screenshot of my current model without the margins. When I zoom to the model bouding box, I get too many margins.
current result
And that's what I'm trying to achieve :
expected result
I've trying to crop the image based on the screen coordinantes but nothing seems to work.
Does anyone can provide some help ?

Cropping the image this way should be doable with the Viewer SDK (see this blog post), although it would be quite a bit of work.
Here's a different idea, how about cropping the screenshot after it's been generated by the Viewer SDK? You could render the screenshot with a blank white background, and later you could have a small piece of code that would cut out all the white pixels above/below/next to your floorplan.
